# No suitable driver found for JDBC Netbeans

Tags: java, mysql-connector

I just started learning java. I'm trying to make a MySql connection with JDBC, but I get the error "No suitable driver found" even though I add the Connector file to the library.
[here it is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZVXO.png)

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class Main {
static String user ="root";
static String password="12345";
static String url = "jbdc:mysql://localhost:3306/world";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws 
ClassNotFoundException  {

        Connection connection=null;
    
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            connection=DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, 
password);
            System.out.println("baglanti basarili");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post code instead of images of code.

Comment: *jbdc*:mysql://localhost - jdbc not jbdc

Comment: I wonder why people still do that `Class.forName(...)`, its obsolete for 10 or 15 years or so.

Comment: Actually, I didn't do it in the first place. But when I saw people doing it, I wanted to try it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the double slashes `//world` before your database name might be the issue. Change it to `/world`.

Comment: Exactly what I was about to suggest.

Comment: i tried it but it didn't work

Comment: the "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" looks like a type (the .cj part)

Comment: but also what @siarhei987 said, above

Comment: @user21298588 `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` is the correct driver classname for MySQL Connector/J 8. The problem is the OP used prefix `jbdc`, not `jdbc`.

Comment: thanks guys, i think it's time to see a doctor for my eyes